# what does the flag "?debugmode=false" do when you append it at the end of a web url

Tags: json, rest

I made a change in a js file and to test it, I had to input "?debugmode=false" in the url .

Without the flag mode it seems my UI change (a change in a POST json request, adding a new parameter) is not picked up.

why the change works when adding debugmode=false? will it affect the UI code in any way ?

Comment: in most cases nothing, in some cases an error might be reported in other case, which implement a handling of such query parameter, some special logic will be applied that maybe prevent debug output or some other logic implemented by the service-provider. There is no general rule to it actually

Comment: the dojo project works only with this flag when I make the change in my js file. Is it recommended to be used in production ? any issues from a security perspective ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the dojo framework, also your question lacks this information to be more precise. Read up what the documentation states about this flag. IMO it seems odd having to disable debug mode explicitely. I'd rather enable it by passing `debugmode=true` and seeing the production case as default

Comment: So there is a web application server hosting a dojo application. To test a change in the application js file, I was recommended this 'hack'. I believe the flag is not required if we restart the app server.

Comment: The real reason i am told is as follows :   For performance reasons individual javascript files are compressed into a single large js file that is loaded when the page loads.  When you make a change in the individual javascript file the page is still loading from the large compressed file so you don't see your change.  When you specify debugmode=false the UI loads all the javascript files individually instead of loading the large compress javascript file.